# How to populate the fields of a subclass based on a superclass in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

I have a base Summary class below:

```
public Class Summary{
    private String name;
    private String status;
    private String id;

// Getters and setters
}
```

I then extended this class to get Customer summary:

```
public Class CustomerSummary extends Summary{
    private String lastLogin;
    private String address;

// Getters and setters
}
```

Now I am calling a Rest endpoint that maps the response to Summary object. I then need to set the lastLogin and address calling another rest endpoint and return the combined data as CustomerSummary object.

```
Summary summary = restClient.getStatus("1234");
CustomerSummary customer = new CustomerSummary()
```

How do I set all the inherited fields of customer object same a as the summary object? I can't cast since I will have to down cast and will run into ClassCastException.

I may have 10s of fields so calling setters of customer object for all the fileds of summary object will result in a lot of duplicate code. Is there a smarter way to handle this?

Comment: `customer.setName(summary.getName());`

Answer (score 5):

You could make a "copy-constructor"

```
protected Summary(Summary template){
   this.name = template.name;
   // ....
}
```

and call that from your subclasses

```
CustomerSummary(Summary template){
    super(template);
}
```

so that you can do

```
Summary summary = restClient.getStatus("1234");
CustomerSummary customer = new CustomerSummary(summary);
```

Comment: Doing it this way means that only there only needs to be one place where the code needs to know all the fields of the Summary class, and that place is inside the Summary class. This makes it much easier to maintain when fields are added :-)